# jqGrid Date format sorting in DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable, gridview-sorting

I want to sort date in the jqgrid. Below is my code line.

Data.push({ label: 'Upload Date', name: 'UploadedDate', width: 300,formatter:'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: "d/m/Y" }});

I have also tried :

Data.push({ label: 'Upload Date', name: 'UploadedDate', width: 300, sorttype: 'date', sopt: ['cn'] });

The problem with 2nd option is that it sorts only with dd and not with month or year. Pls suggest.

Comment: I have also tried :  Data.push({ label: 'Upload Date', name: 'UploadedDate', width: 300,sorttype: 'date', align: "right", formatter: 'date',formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'D, M d, H:i A'}});        The date format is Tue, Jul 11, 11:56 AM. I expect dd/mm/yyyy or a datetime in same format.

Comment: Your question does not have full information in order to get help. Can you please post your jqGrid setup? Is your data local or the sorting is at server side (datatype 'json'). With your code you tell us oinly the setting for the column, which is not enough